# Rules: Steps to trigger a rule when a field is updated

Tags: 6, rules

I am using the rules module to send an email when a particular CCK field `field_test` is changed. These are the steps I performed:

```
Event: After updating existing content
Condition: Field has changed
```

Under Field I chose `field_test`.
Under DO I chose the action as email.

My issue is that even if any other field is updated under that content type, it still triggers my rule, under debugging it shows Condition `Updated content's field 'field_test' has been changed` evaluated to TRUE.

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of field is field_test?

Comment: Hmm... It looks like they had this issue a couple years ago, including with textfields, but the issue was marked fixed. Be sure to update to the latest version of CCK though that's probably not the issue.

Comment: @jordojuice Aah.. it was just that. We are using a website whose modules have not been upgraded :( Thanks a ton!

Comment: Great! :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured what my issue was. I had an earlier version of the CCK module (6.x-2.1) and once upgraded to the latest version (6.x-2.9) the rule behaves as expected.

Thanks to jordojuice for pointing me in the right direction.